# Create own shape for panel with GraphicsPath

Tags: c#

How to set the region like this following picture?

[image: Example of panel I want to insert later]

The square I draw was the panel that I want to insert.
Let say the panel size was new Size(200, 500).
Then I want to remove the region of the panel in the middle (with label b and the region was color with blue).
Let say the region was 50,50 in size and the location was 50, 250
how to remove that blue region?

This is what I have done

```
    GraphicsPath a = new GraphicsPath();
     Rectangle RectangleRegion = new Rectangle(new point(50, 250), new Size(50,50));
    graphicsPath.addRectangle (RectangleRegion) 

Panel myPanel = new panel(){new Size(200, 500), new Pont(0,0), region = new region(a);
```

With this method, it doesn't remove the area I want to have
it just remove the other part I want to keep and it keep the part i want to remove.

Comment: Use two regions and Region.Exclude. (And learn about punctuation!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **two** `Regions` and `Region.Exclude`:

```
Region r1 = new Region(new Rectangle(11,11,111,111));
Region r2 = new Region(new Rectangle(33,33,66,66));
r1.Exclude(r2);

panel1.Region = r1;
```

[image]

For more complex shapes you will indeed want to create the `Regions` from `GraphicsPaths`.