# Draw transparent rectangles on image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, gdi+

I want to create an overlay on an image, similar to the one in the picture.

Creating the translucent cover is easy, I just create a rectangle the size of the image and give it a low alpha value.

How can I get the transparent "cut-outs" though?  Drawing over the image again just increases its alpha value.  I need to explicitly set it to zero.

```
var image = picOriginal.Image;
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
var color = Color.FromArgb(200, Color.Black);
var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
var transparentColor = Color.Transparent;
var transparentBrush = new SolidBrush(transparentColor);
var rectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size);
graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);
graphics.FillEllipse(transparentBrush, 100, 100, 100, 150);

var bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
picGenerated.Image = bitmap;
```

[image: Overlay]

Comment: Did you tried: [Bitmap.MakeTransparent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: You can [`SetClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.setclip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#overloads) the `Graphics` object to a suitable  [`Region`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region(v=vs.110).aspx). `Exclude` the areas from the full Region. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991408/create-own-shape-for-panel-with-graphicspath/45995983#45995983)

Comment: This `g.SetClip(new Rectangle(212, 123, 34, 45), CombineMode.Exclude);` will cut one small hole into the grawing area.. You can use it several times or combine all sorts of shapes into a GraphicsPath instead of the Rectangle..

Comment: @Taw Regions was indeed the answer, no need for clip just exclude operations was enough.  If you want to put it as an answer I'll give it a tick.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I do not write answers here anymore, though.. Feel free to post the code you used as an answer yourself..